# Isomorphic react-router-redux syncHistory middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

`syncHistory` from `react-router-redux` takes in an argument that is `browserHistory` from `react-router`. On the server, calling `syncHistory(browserHistory)` does not really work. I am trying to create a store with middleware:

```
const { syncHistory } from 'react-router-redux'
const { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
const { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'

const reduxRouterMiddleware = syncHistory(browserHistory)
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
  routerReduxMiddleware
)(createStore)
```

On the server, I get the following error:

```
    unsubscribeHistory = history.listen(function (location) {
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'listen' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have observed `browserHistory` will not work on the server as it uses the History API that is built into the browser. On the server you have to substitute it for something like `history/lib/createMemoryHistory`, e.g.

```
import createHistory from 'history/lib/createMemoryHistory';

const reduxRouterMiddleware = syncHistory(createHistory);
...
```

See the React Router [documentation](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#creatememoryhistory) for more information on history.

---

As of React Router 2,
[docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/CHANGES.md#v200-rc4),
 createMemoryHistory is included as a part of the React Router.

```
import createHistory from 'react-router/lib/createMemoryHistory';
```